# How to add more ringtones to an Alarm class in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, alarm, ringtone

I am using the [Alarm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class for my alarm app in windows phone. I have included 5 ringtones but now users want more...

I believe 3rd party apps don't have access to system ringtones, so how about using Songs from Music Library?

However, after digging into it, I've found there's no way to get the URIs of the songs and I will have to use them as the Alarm class is expecting a [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm.sound%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) type for its Sound property.

So, is it just impossive for my alarm app to give users the option to have more ringtones??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the media that is on your device. The only real way is to host the ringtones on a server so that your app can download them.

Comment: +1 Thanks for clarifying this. I know this is not part of the question but there would be legal issues if I just put ringtones up on the server right??